# how to trigger a ng-show function from angular-ui tab select

Tags: angularjs

I can usually trigger a function from a Angular-Ui tab by using the select attribute. In this situation I cannot make it work. I am using a ng-show function to display a message inbox. Everything is working fine except when I am viewing a open email I cannot get back to the inbox list. I need be able to click on the Inbox tab and return to the main list. right now it does nothing and it throws no errors.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7PLT7nFgxvNtxebfSDjo?p=preview)

```
 <tabset justified="true">
   <tab heading="Inbox" select="setcurrentView(1)">
     <div ng-show="currentView === 1" src="'inbox.html'" ng-include=""></div>
     <div ng-show="currentView === 2" src="'videoEmailVisit.html'" ng-include=""></div>
   </tab>
   <tab heading="Sent">
     <div src="'sent.html'" ng-include=""></div>
   </tab>
   <tab heading="Archive">
    <div src="'archive.html'" ng-include=""></div>
   </tab>
 </tabset>

  <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-striped">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>From</th>
       <th>Type of Service</th>
       <th>Date</th>
       <th>Category</th>
       <th>MR#</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Dr. John Doe</td>
        <td ng-click="setcurrentView(2);"><a>Video Email Visit</a></td>
        <td>3/12/2015</td>
        <td>Video Email Visit</td>
        <td>4448</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>

  $scope.currentView = 1;
$scope.setcurrentView = function (messageType) {
    $scope.currentView = messageType;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDITED]
Add (or replace the 'select' directive) this attribute in your 'Inbox' tab.

```
ng-click="setcurrentView(1)"
```

I know this is not the most elegant way to do this but it should solve your problem.

Comment: small side effect, it does not allow me to re-select another email with refreshing the page

Comment: ng-click="setcurrentView(1)"